# How do I use an id from the layout file of a listview?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have three classes:

- MainActivity
- MoviesFragment
- ImageAdapter

The fragments XML layout file contains a ListView. The listview has a different layout file which I use to design how each movie is displayed in the list. As in poster and title.

The MoviesFragment gets the urls of the movie posters from the API and puts it into an ArrayList < HashMap >.

This HashMap is passed onto the ImageAdapter which states how the ListView is populated.

The poster image is set to the ImageView from the ImageAdapter class, however, it's not finding the id.

**ImageAdapter:**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> array;
    private int width;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> paths, int x) {
        mContext = context;
        array = paths;
        width = x;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return array.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        Drawable d = resizeDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.place_holder_img));
        Picasso.with(mContext).load("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185" + array.get(position)).resize(width, (int) (width * 1.5)).placeholder(d).into(imageView);

        return imageView;
    }

    private Drawable resizeDrawable(Drawable image) {
        Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) image).getBitmap();
        Bitmap bitmapResized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, (int) (width * 1.5), false);
        return new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(), bitmapResized);
    }
}
```

**MoviesFragment:**

```
public class MoviesFragment extends Fragment {

    static int width;
    static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> posters;
    static ListView listView;
    static boolean sortByPop;

    public MoviesFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

        Point size = new Point();

        display.getSize(size);

        if (MainActivity.TABLET) {
            width = size.x / 6;
        } else width = size.x / 3;

        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvMovies);

        //if fragment is visible
        if (getActivity() != null) {
        }

        //handles listView item click
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                System.out.println(posters.get(position));
            }
        });        
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        getActivity().setTitle("Most Popular Movies");

        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
            listView.setVisibility(ListView.VISIBLE);
            new ImageLoadTask().execute();
        } else {
            TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
            RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)
            getActivity().findViewById(R.id.relativelayout);
            textView.setText("You are not connected to the internet!");
            if (layout.getChildCount() == 1) {
                layout.addView(textView);
            }
            listView.setVisibility(ListView.GONE);
        }
    }

    public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();

    }

    private class ImageLoadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    //generates the amount of inputs
                    String[] array = new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "5"};
                    posters = new ArrayList<>(getPathFromAPI(array, sortByPop));

                    return posters;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
            if (result != null && getActivity() != null) {
                //puts the images into the imageviews
                ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(getActivity(), result, width);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
        }

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPathFromAPI(String[] movieID, boolean sort) {
        //gets movies and puts them into the posters arrayList
        posters = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String aMovieID : movieID) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("id", "/kqjL17yufvn9OVLyXYpvtyrFfak.jpg");
            posters.add(map);
        }
        return posters;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static boolean TABLET = false;

    public boolean isTablet(Context context) {
        boolean xlarge = ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &
                Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == 4);
        boolean large = ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &
                Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE);
        return (xlarge || large);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.relativelayout, new MoviesFragment())
                    .commit();
        }


    }
}
```

**XML for the ListView layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <ImageView android:id="@+id/ivPosters"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/results_layout_tv_movie_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="hellow"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out your ImageAdapter. `@Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {}` you should inflate your layout and find id.
Just like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.yourlayout, null);
        tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv);
        iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv);
       }
```

Comment: It worked. Sort of. The lines inside the getview have to go into an if statement which checks if view is null. If it is it creates the elements

Comment: Yeah,i forgot it. really need `if (view == null) {}`

Answer (score 0):

You want to have the adapter to build the entire row. [simple example](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter)